# Javascript create array from existing split on property value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to iterate over an existing array with of objects with a 'quantity' property and rebuild it by a control value.

```
let cart = [{id: 1, name: 'Pizza', quantity: 5, specialId: 0},
            {id: 2, name: 'Burger', quantity: 2, specialId: 0}];
```

I have a control of 3 items i.e. for every 3 items you get a discount so I'd like to reconstitute the cart array as follows:

```
cart = [{id: 1, name: 'Pizza', quantity: 3, specialId: 1}, 
        {id: 2, name: 'Pizza', quantity: 2, specialId: 2},
        {id: 3, name: 'Burger', quantity: 1, specialId: 2},
        {id: 4, name: 'Burger', qty: 1, specialId: 0}]
```

I've looked at several ways of doing this mostly around creating a new array of single quantity items and then creating another final array but surely that isn't very efficient?

I'd appreciate any pointers. I have a horrible feeling I'm missing something simple and have stared at this too long.

Comment: Why would the Burger get split in two records when its quantity is only 2 ?

Comment: also could the initial cart contain a second record with `Pizza` ?

Comment: Are you sure you need to be splitting the objects in the first place?

Comment: Why `quantity`  and `qty`?

Comment: premature optimization....

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli no it can't, the split is to create specials i.e. for every 3 products you buy, you get a free item etc

Comment: What is the purpose of `specialId`?

Comment: also what about the new IDs and the sorting in your array can you make a full example of your case ?

Comment: @trincot that's the grouping. i.e. for every 3 items in your cart you get a free item so on checkout I'd like to display the cart by special.

Comment: I don't really know what that means "display the cart by special". Do you mean you want to identify every complete set of 3 items with a unique specialId, and attribute zero to items that are not part of a complete set? If so, please update your question in order to clarify this and other points raised in the comments section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly the amount of three is ignorant of the type of product, so the second batch of three (in your example) consists of 2 pizzas and 1 burger.

The `specialId` seems to be unique and non-zero for every complete set of three (where every item in that set shares that `specialId` value), and zero for any remaining item(s).

Finally, it seems that the `id` in the result is unrelated to the input, but just an incremental number.

Here is how you could do that:

```js
function splitBy(cart, size) {
    const result = [];
    let quantity = 0;
    let grab = size;
    let specialId = 1;
    let id = 1;
    for (let item of cart) {
        for (quantity = item.quantity; quantity >= grab; quantity -= grab, grab = size, specialId++) {
            if (result.length && !result[result.length-1].specialId) result[result.length-1].specialId = specialId;
            result.push(Object.assign({}, item, {quantity: grab, specialId, id: id++}));
        }
        if (quantity) result.push(Object.assign({}, item, {quantity, specialId: 0, id: id++}));
        grab = size - quantity;
    }
    return result;
}

const cart = [{id: 1, name: 'Pizza', quantity: 5, specialId: 0},
              {id: 2, name: 'Burger', quantity: 2, specialId: 0}];
const result = splitBy(cart, 3)

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks. That is quite clever and fast. //Attributed @trincot

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have two options.

1. loop over the current `cart`, and if the quantity is over 3, split it to two, and push them both.
2. split the array, and then merge it together.

My guess is to go with the first option, doing something like this:

```
var cart = [{id: 1, name: 'Pizza', quantity: 5, specialId: 0},
    {id: 2, name: 'Burger', quantity: 2, specialId: 0}];
var a = [];

cart.forEach(x => {
 if (x.quantity > 3) {
    let temp = {...x};
    temp.quantity = 3;
    a.push(temp);
    x.quantity -= 3;
  }
  a.push(x)
});
```

Comment: Thanks. That is an interesting pointer but won't work as it will result in incorrect quantities i.e Pizza 3, Pizza 2, Burger 2

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your question correctly, I assumed your condition for a discount is 3 of the same product. If it doesn't have to be the same product, just change the if condition to be a counter that gets reset when it reaches 3, and then pushes the result to the array.